# Customize Django-Registration-Redux Form

Tags: css, django, django-registration

This is how I get my registration redux form:
[image]

Its looks really messed up. Can you please tell me how to apply some CSS to my form that is built via Registration redux so that it appears as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For fast way you can use [crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and just call it by `{{ form|cryspy }}`
Or you can look at classes, which automatically added in form and update it in your css file.